# Does --nodekey work with geth or just bootnode?

Tags: go-ethereum, node-discovery, bootnodes, cli, enode

In the options for geth I see `--nodekey` listed but I can't seem to get it to **(re)generate** an enode url when starting a full node. When starting a bootnode this works for me as expected.

So should `geth --nodkey=key.txt"` be **(re)generating the same enode** like I'm expecting or does that only work with `bootnode --nodkey=key.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `geth --nodkey=key.txt` will (re)generate the same enode url repeatedly as the cli options would suggest. It wasn't working for me due to the unfortunate combination of a typo in my sh script and a bad nodekey file.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#admin_nodeinfo

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://44826a5d6a55f88a18298bca4773fca5749cdc3a5c9f308aa7d810e9b31123f3e7c5fba0b1d70aac5308426f47df2a128a6747040a3815cc7dd7167d03be320d@[::]:30303",
  id: "44826a5d6a55f88a18298bca4773fca5749cdc3a5c9f308aa7d810e9b31123f3e7c5fba0b1d70aac5308426f47df2a128a6747040a3815cc7dd7167d03be320d",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30303",
  name: "Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.6",
  ports: {
    discovery: 30303,
    listener: 30303
  },
  protocols: {
    eth: {
      difficulty: 17334254859343145000,
      genesis: "0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3",
      head: "0xb83f73fbe6220c111136aefd27b160bf4a34085c65ba89f24246b3162257c36a",
      network: 1
    }
  }
}
```

when starting you node, the enode is also printed during the startup process

Comment: I reworded my question to be clearer. I'm trying to use geth like bootnode to get a consistent enode.

Comment: the enode is deterministic and will not change. The IP of your node might change if it's a dynamic one though. So start your geth node you wanna use as a bootnode. Save the enode (copy-past works perfect) in a file. Then start a second node with the option `--bootnodes 'enodeOfYourGethNodePreviouslySaved@itsIp:itsPort'`